# Tool allowing to resume and bookmark specific location of video/playlist

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, bookmarks, windows-media-player, media-player-classic

I am going insane trying to watch a course of videos on a bunch of different folders. I aggregated all the folders into one huge playlist (in different Windows players) but each time i resume watching, I can't remember what video I last watched in the playlist.

Whats is it possible to "bookmark" locations in Windows media player or other players allowing for this functionality? Would be nice if they even remember last played video/location when reopening playlist so that you don't even have to bookmark when closing the player.

EDIT: I noticed that Windows media Player Classic has this option built in:
[image]

Comment: [Using Custom Bookmarks in VLC Media Player](https://www.vlchelp.com/using-custom-bookmarks-vlc-media-player/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows Media Player Plus!](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/) plug-in adds 'restore last played' functionality to WMP.